# Convert angle to value & value to angle between range for react slider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, math

I have an arc slider which im using to create a climate control interface with react.

The white knob in this screenshot rotates around the center of the arc, the rotation values are done and this is all working, the white knob is restricted to the visible arc area (50-130deg) is restricted and the values can never be outside the bounds.

I then have a value, and a min/max value which i need to calculate based on the position/rotation of the knob.

I have a really simple function which repositions the handle when the user is dragging:

```
function onDrag(event) {
   const containerBounding = _containerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
   const centerX = containerBounding.left + containerBounding.width / 2;
   const centerY = containerBounding.top + containerBounding.height / 2;
   const x = event.clientX;
   const y = event.clientY;
    
   // Calculate angle between center of container and current drag coordinates
   const angleRad = Math.atan2(centerY - y, centerX - x);
          
   // Convert angle from radians to degrees
   let angleDeg = (angleRad * 180) / Math.PI;
   const minRotation = 50;
   const maxRotation = 130;
   if (angleDeg > minRotation && angleDeg < maxRotation) {
      // Clamp to the closest bound
      angleDeg = angleDeg < (minRotation + maxRotation) / 2 ? minRotation : END_ANGLE;
   }
   _containerRef.current.style.transform = `rotate(${angleDeg}deg)`;
}
```

To give some indication, this is kind of what I'm expecting in terms of results:

```
    const min = 6;
    const max = 30;
    const value = 6;
    const minRotation = 50;
    const maxRotation = 130;
```

```
50deg - 6 // the minimum rotation, so the minimum value
-1deg - 11
-90deg - 21
-173deg - 27
130deg - 36  // the maximum rotation, so the maximum value
```

This has been hard for me because i cannot figure out how to convert this degree to a value becuse the rotation value changes from positive to negative as you're rotating/dragging the handle, here's what I've tried:

```
export function angleToValue(params: {
  degree: number;
  min: number;
  max: number;
}) {
  const { degree, min, max } = params;
  // Normalize the angle to be within the continuous range of the arc
  let normalizedAngle = degree < -90 ? degree + 360 : degree;

  // Determine the midpoint angle, which corresponds to the midpoint value
  const midRotation = -90; // Degrees
  const midValue = (min + max) / 2;

  // Linearly interpolate the value based on the position within the arc
  let value;
  if (normalizedAngle <= midRotation) {
    value = min + ((normalizedAngle - 50) / (midRotation - 50)) * (midValue - min);
  } else {
    value = midValue + ((normalizedAngle - midRotation) / (130 - midRotation)) * (max - midValue);
  }

  return value;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simplify building the formula, I introduced an intermediate quantity, `ang280` that increases (linearly) from zero
to 280, when the `angle` goes from 50 to 0 to -180/180 and down to 130. We then have these corresponding values for the
three quantintities:

```
angle   50  ->  0  -> -180===180 -> 130  (decreasing except jump discontinuity at 180)
ang280   0  -> 50  ->     230    -> 280  (increasing)
value    6  ->                   ->  36  (increasing)
```

`value` and `ang280` are related by a direct linear relation: `value = ang280/280 * 30 + 6`, while
the relation between `angle` and `ang280` is given by two different formulae for left and right of angle = -180/180.

With these, the functions would be:

```js
function angleToValue(angle){
    const ang280 = (angle <= 50) ? 50 - angle : 410 - angle;
    if(angle > 50 && angle < 130){throw new Error('Invalid angle');}
    return ang280/280 * 30 + 6
}

console.log('angle = 50    value = ' + angleToValue(50));
console.log('angle = 0     value = ' + angleToValue(0));
console.log('angle = -90   value = ' + angleToValue(-90));
console.log('angle = -180  value = ' + angleToValue(-180));
console.log('angle = 180   value = ' + angleToValue(180));
console.log('angle = 130   value = ' + angleToValue(130));
console.log(Array(40).fill('-').join(''));

function valueToAngle(value){
    if(value < 6 || value > 36){throw new Error('Invalid value')}
    const ang280 = (value - 6)/30*280;
    return ang280 >= 230 ? 410 - ang280 : 50 - ang280;
}

console.log('value =    6  angle = ' + valueToAngle(6));
console.log('value =   21  angle = ' + valueToAngle(21));
console.log('value = 30.6  angle = ' + valueToAngle(30.6));
console.log('value = 30.7  angle = ' + valueToAngle(30.7));
console.log('value =   36  angle = ' + valueToAngle(36));
```

Obviously, typescript signatures might be:

```ts
function valueToAngle(value: number): number;
function angleToValue(angle: number): number;
```

I left the snippet in plain js to make it runnable here.

And the general forms, for dynamic values of the `angle` and `value` at the two ends of the gauge, that I called for brevity `A` and `B` and should be understood as `Min` and `Max` or `Left` and `Right`:

```js
function angleToValue(angle, angleA, angleB, valueA, valueB){
    const angZeroAtA = angle <= angleA ? angleA - angle : angleA + 360 - angle;
    if(angle > angleA && angle < angleB){throw new Error('Invalid angle');}
    return angZeroAtA / (360 + angleA - angleB ) * (valueB - valueA) + valueA
}

console.log('angle = 50    value = ' + angleToValue(50, 50, 130, 6, 36));
console.log('angle = 0     value = ' + angleToValue(0, 50, 130, 6, 36));
console.log('angle = -90   value = ' + angleToValue(-90, 50, 130, 6, 36));
console.log('angle = -180  value = ' + angleToValue(-180, 50, 130, 6, 36));
console.log('angle = 180   value = ' + angleToValue(180, 50, 130, 6, 36));
console.log('angle = 130   value = ' + angleToValue(130, 50, 130, 6, 36));
console.log(Array(40).fill('-').join(''))

function valueToAngle(value, angleA, angleB, valueA, valueB){
    if(value < valueA || value > valueB){throw new Error('Invalid value')}
    const angZeroAtA = (value - valueA)/(valueB - valueA) * (360 + angleA - angleB );
    return angZeroAtA >= 180 + angleA ? 360 + angleA - angZeroAtA : angleA - angZeroAtA;
}

console.log('value =    6  angle = ' + valueToAngle(6, 50, 130, 6, 36));
console.log('value =   21  angle = ' + valueToAngle(21, 50, 130, 6, 36));
console.log('value = 30.64  angle = ' + valueToAngle(30.64, 50, 130, 6, 36));
console.log('value = 30.65  angle = ' + valueToAngle(30.65, 50, 130, 6, 36));
console.log('value =   36  angle = ' + valueToAngle(36, 50, 130, 6, 36));
```

This only works, of course, for the same setting of a decreasing `angle` that passes through the jump at -180/180.